# unable to find "preferences" in sql developer on mac

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to add sql server JDBC driver to oracle sql developer on mac.
I do not find "preferences" under tools option.

Is there any other way to add the driver?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac applications (almost) always have their preferences under the application-name menu that comes immediately after the Apple menu. In the Human Interface Guidelines [that is referred to as 'the App menu'](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/the-menu-bar).

So look under the 'Oracle SQL Developer' menu next to the Apple logo - that is where 'Preferences' (up to macOS 12) or 'Settings' (from macOS 13) lives.

[image]

---

As of macOS 13 (Ventura), the menu item has been renamed from 'Preferences' to 'Settings', but otherwise works the same. The HIG now has that name.

Comment: this has changed a bit (March 23,2023), however thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to settings.
   [image]
2. Search for drivers.

[image]

3. Select Add Entry.
   [image]
4. 

[image]